# Programmatically filter document library view

Tags: document-library, filter

I am starting a SharePoint application where I need to filter a document library dynamically when a user visits a page.

Is this possible?  If yes, how?
Is it possible to have an application page with a document library on it?

i.e. a user visits an application page which has a document library on it.  As the user opens the page i want to filter the documents in the library based on some user contextual information (say department) where department is a column of the meta data

(another scenario, on the application page i have a dropdownlist, after the user makes a selection i want to show specific documents based on the user selection

Answer (score 1):

If it is simple functionality, could you use the inbuilt filter web parts:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-filter-web-parts-HA010033786.aspx#BM2

- Current User Filter (and select Department)
- Choice Filter (for the drop down)

Comment: Is there a way to do this through code? (after page loads?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a connection from another webpart. Have one webpart where the user selects a department and then have that value linked to the library web part so it can filter the view.

Comment: How could I create a webpart that is abble to be linked to the library webpart?